# Using getNodeSet on XMLNodeSet (XML package)

Tags: xml, r

I have trouble using the R XML package for a specific application I have in mind. Consider the following example document. I am interested in getting the information in b inside the first a node. But the nature of my problem (application) is so that I first **need** to identify all the a nodes in the document and then subset this nodeset to get the first a node and then get the b node. The first step is easy:

```
    doc <- "
    <div></div>
    <a id='1'><b id='3'>text1</b></a>
    <a id='2'><b id='4'>text2</b></a>
    "
    parsed <- htmlParse(doc)

    step1 <- getNodeSet(parsed, "//a")

    > step1

    [[1]]

    <a id="1">

      <b id="3">text1</b>

    </a> 


    [[2]]

    <a id="2">

      <b id="4">text2</b>

    </a> 


    attr(,"class")

    [1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

This yields the expected results. The next step in my application is to extract the b nodes from the first a node. If I use getNodeSet on step1[[1]], I get the b nodes from both nodes in the step1 nodeset.

```
    step2 <- getNodeSet(step1[[1]], "//b")
    step2

    [[1]]
    <b id="3">text1</b> 

    [[2]]
    <b id="4">text2</b> 

    attr(,"class")
    [1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

I figured out that I could use the XPath "b" to get the information in this example, but ultimately I need "//b" to work here. The way I understand the XML package works, I don't think this behaviour is a bug, but a consequence of the reference of the C-level representation of this document. Is there a way I can achieve this "two-step" process by any way? I essentially want step[[1]] to work like a fresh document.

Comment: You can use `"//a[1]/b"` for your XPATH. That will give you all the `b` nodes that are children of the first `a` node. `parsed["//a[1]/b"]` would get you what you want most likely. If you must use `step1` then you can use `.` for example `getNodeSet(step1[[1]], "./b")` to refer to the current node.

Comment: I know the XPath solution for this problem. My question is about  how I can reinitialize the step1[[1]] nodeset so it works like a fresh document, and I can have a "two-step" approach for this problem.

Comment: The solution is to use `.` as I mentioned. Alternatively if you must you can do `xmlParse(saveXML(step1[[1]]))["//b"]`. `newXMLDoc(step1[[1]])["//b"]` would also work.

Comment: The detour via saveXML is what I needed. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of methods that can be used to achieve what you want. Firstly you can adjust your XPATH:

```
doc <- "
    <div></div>
    <a id='1'><b id='3'>text1</b></a>
    <a id='2'><b id='4'>text2</b></a>
    "
parsed <- htmlParse(doc)
parsed["//a[1]/b"]

> parsed["//a[1]/b"]
[[1]]
<b id="3">text1</b> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

If you require to work from your `step1` you can use relative referencing in your XPATH:

```
step1 <- getNodeSet(parsed, "//a")
getNodeSet(step1[[1]], "./b")

> getNodeSet(step1[[1]], "./b")
[[1]]
<b id="3">text1</b> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

To work with `step1[[1]]` as if it was a new XML document there are two methods which may suit:

```
mydoc2 <- xmlParse(saveXML(step1[[1]]))

> mydoc2["//b"]
[[1]]
<b id="3">text1</b> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

and possibly better is:

```
mydoc3 <- xmlDoc(step1[[1]])

> mydoc3["//b"]
[[1]]
<b id="3">text1</b> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```